# Using multirow with an equation

Tags: tables, math-mode, multirow

If I use the  math mode immediately behind a multirow-statement, LaTeX gives me an error (and without the math mode it works fine). The following source code will not compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\multirow{2}{*} $x_A$ & $k$ \\
                      & b \\
\multirow{2}{*} B & k \\
                  & b \\    
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Why is this so, and how to achieve it to put an equation into a row spanning multiple rows?

Comment: Because you have to enclose what you want to go over multiple rows in braces.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Would you like to add this as an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of multirow requires you to pass three arguments. The last one is the text that should print over more than one line. So you need something like:

```
\multirow{2}{*}{$x_A$} & $k$\\
```